# Redirect http/8080 to https/8443 does not work with Firefox and IE: redirect goes to https/8080

Tags: internet-explorer, tomcat, firefox, ssl, redirect

We want to redirect http/8080 to https/8443 with Tomcat 8.5. When requesting the http-URL in Firefox 51.x or IE 11 the URL is redirected to `https://server:8080`  instead of  `https://server:8443`

This is `conf/server.xml`

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           maxKeepAliveRequests="1" />

<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate ... />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

This is `conf/web.xml`

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>server</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

The following is the output when running `wget`

```
$ wget http://server:8080/ -S
--2017-02-13 14:37:09--  http://server:8080/
Resolving server... <IP>
Connecting to server|<IP>|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 302
  Cache-Control: private
  Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
  Location: https://server:8443/
  Content-Length: 0
  Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2017 13:37:09 GMT
  Connection: close
Location: https://server:8443/ [following]
--2017-02-13 14:37:09--  https://server:8443/
Connecting to server|<IP>|:8443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 200
  Cache-Control: private
  Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  ETag: W/"1288-1363105010000"
  Last-Modified: Tue, 12 Mar 2013 16:16:50 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Length: 1288
  Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2017 13:37:09 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
Length: 1288 (1.3K) [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html'
```

As you can see the response is a redirect (Status `302`) to the expected location `https://server:8443/`. The connections on the original request is closed thanks to `maxKeepAliveRequests="1"`. Everything works fine with `wget`.

However, when entering `http://server:8080/` into the address line of Firefox or IE it gets redirected to `https://server:8080/`: the port does not change.

**Edit:** When `server` is change to the server's IP (`http://IP:8080/`) Firefox and IE follows the redirect to `https://IP:8443/` as expected.

**Edit 2:** When the cache is cleaned than the first URL redirect works as expected while the second one fails again. This is true for Firefox as well as IE.
What is going wrong?

Comment: Did you use the debug view in Firefox to see the redirect?

Comment: @Michael-O Yes, I did. However, after switching to the wrong URL the response from the first request is lost from the network analysis tool. See my second edit on the original post.

Comment: Claude, resort to wireshark. You'll see what is sent by the server and wether Firefox tries to establish an TLS session to your desired port. Note: Firebug will retain redirect requests in the console tab.